# How to make a library configurable in Rails initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a library(wrapper) that will interact with AWS Kinesis. I want the library to be configurable like [Rollbar](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem#rack) and many other libraries.

I'm also looking into [the code](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/master/lib/rollbar.rb) and try to understand how they do it. Still, I don't think I understand it completely. I think they are using middleware to handle this but not sure how to configure this for my use case.

I will want to have a file `.../initializers/firehose.rb` and the content can look something like this:

```
Firehose.configure do |config|
  config.stream_name = ENV['AWS_KINESIS_FIREHOSE_STREAM']
  config.region = ENV['AWS_KINESIS_FIREHOSE_REGION']
  #.. more config here
end
```

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think they are using middleware to handle this

Nope, no middleware. It's a plain ruby [block usage](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/fa69fcf72734c6049fa3e316db690bcfbdc722ff/lib/rollbar.rb#L64-L69).

Here's how a minimal/barebones implementation could look.

```
class Configuration
  attr_accessor :host, :port
end

class MyService
  attr_reader :configuration

  def initialize
    @configuration = Configuration.new
  end

  def configure(&block)
    block.call(configuration)
  end
end

service = MyService.new

service.configuration # => #<Configuration:0x007fefa9084530>
service.configuration.host # => nil


service.configure do |config|
  config.host = 'http://example.com'
  config.port = 8080
end

service.configuration # => #<Configuration:0x007fefa9084530 @host="http://example.com", @port=8080>
service.configuration.host # => "http://example.com"
```

As you can see, there's nothing complicated here. Just passing objects around.

Comment: Oh, I get this, I have few doubts like how will this `service` object be available anywhere else in the code?

Comment: @aks: normally, you have this `configure` method on the class itself (rather than its instances), which is naturally available everywhere. That's a minor adjustment, which I leave to you.